# when doubling my stack it give me critical section error ! _ctrlvalidHeappointer

Tags: c++

I have written a class `Stack` whose both sides are used, i.e. two stacks in one.
One from `[0]` until `[someplace - 1]` and one from `[capacity-1]` until `[someplace +1]`.

Everything is fine but I have some problems with doubling the memory when my array is full.
My code works for doubling at first, but when it needs to double some more it gives me some weird error.

> _ctrlvalidHeappointer
>
> critical section error

This is my code. There is some explanation in the code too. When I push too many element in the stack it fails.

```
    string firstname = "asasasasasaasasasasassasasasaasas";
    string secondname= "asasdasfregeasasasasasgergergererg";
        for (int i = 0; i < firstname.length(); i++)
        {
            a.push_at_first(firstname.at(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < secondname.length(); i++)
        {
            a.push_from_end(secondname.at(i));
        }
```

It is my class

```
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Stack{
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    Stack(const Stack<T>& ob);
    void double_size();
    void push_at_first(T mydata);
    void push_from_end(T mydata);
    T & operator = (Stack<T> ob);
private:
    int top;
    int top2;
    T * stack;
    int capacity;
};
template <class T>
T& Stack<T>::operator = (Stack<T> ob)
{
    if(capacity == ob.capacity){
        top = ob.top;
        top2 = ob.top2;
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            stack[i] = ob.stack[i];
        }
        return *this;}
    else
    {
        capacity = ob.capacity;
        stack = new T[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            stack[i] = ob.stack[i];
        }

    }
}


template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack (const Stack<T>& ob) :capacity(ob.capacity)
{
    
    stack = new T[capacity];
    top = ob.top;
    top2=ob.top2;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        stack[i] = ob.stack[i];
    }
}
template <class T>
 Stack<T>::~Stack()
  {
delete [] stack;
   }
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    capacity = 17;
    top = 0;
    top2 = capacity-1;
    stack = new T[capacity];
}
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push_at_first(T mydata)
{
    if ( (top + 1) == (top2 -1) ) //  1 : because I want to Be a Empty Space between Two Stack so i can tell the difference
        double_size();
    stack[++top] = mydata;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push_from_end(T mydata)
{
    if( (top + 1) == (top2 -1) ) //  1 : because I want to Be a Empty Space between Two Stack so i can tell the difference
        double_size();
    stack[--top2] = mydata;
}

    
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::double_size()
{
Stack<T> temp(*this);
capacity *= 2;
stack = new T[capacity];
top = temp.top;
top2 = capacity - (temp.capacity - temp.top2);// capacity - number of data in stack of temp ;

// if we have something in first stack then copy 0 to top elements of temp.stack to stack
if(top > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= top ; i++)
    {
        stack[i] = temp.stack[i];
    }
}
// There is Something Wrong Down here ! i can't figure out what !
if(top2 < capacity - 1)
{
    for (int i = capacity-1; i >= top2; i--)
    {
        stack[i] = temp.stack[i-(temp.capacity)];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Produce your twenty-line debugging [testcase](http://sscce.org), not this behemoth.

Comment: Edited ! removed unnecessary methods . Thanks for helping.

Comment: it kinda is a bug ! so i think it is a off-topic in there :D !! i think i should let it go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems.

1. You're missing a copy constructor and assignment operator.
2. You're explicitly calling the destructors of the elements.
   This will lead to trouble when `delete` does it again, as it does automatically.
3. You're not allocating the proper amount of memory for `temp.stack` in `double_size`. Even though you have access to the private members of `temp`, you should let it manage itself (see *copy constructor* above).
   (BTW: that variable is unnecessary - just copy from your old memory block to a new one, then delete the old block and assign the new block pointer to `stack`.)
4. There may also be some problems with the indexing in `double_size`, but you should fix those three problems first.

Comment: I have changed those things you mentioned but still i am having same problem .